# How to check if DynamoDB table exists?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm a new user in boto3 and i'm using `DynamoDB`.

I went through over the DynamoDB api and I couldn't find any method which tell me if a table is already exists.

What is the best approach dealing this issue?

Should I try to create a new table and wrap it using try catch ?

Comment: use dynamodb-data-mapper check provides function ensureTableExists, to create table if not exists

Answer (score 108, accepted):

From reading the documentation, I can see that there are three methods by which you can check if a table exists.

1. The [CreateTable API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTable.html) throws an error `ResourceInUseException` if the table already exists. Wrap the create_table method with try except to catch this
2. You can use the [ListTables API](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.list_tables) to get the list of table names associated with the current account and endpoint. Check if the table name is present in the list of table names you get in the response.
3. The [DescribeTable API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTable.html) will throw an error `ResourceNotFoundException` if the table name you request doesn't exist.

To me, the first option sounds better if you just want to create a table.

**Edit:**
I see that some people are finding it difficult to catch the exceptions. I will put some code below for you to know how to handle exceptions in boto3.

**Example 1**

```
import boto3

dynamodb_client = boto3.client('dynamodb')

try:
    response = dynamodb_client.create_table(
        AttributeDefinitions=[
            {
                'AttributeName': 'Artist',
                'AttributeType': 'S',
            },
            {
                'AttributeName': 'SongTitle',
                'AttributeType': 'S',
            },
        ],
        KeySchema=[
            {
                'AttributeName': 'Artist',
                'KeyType': 'HASH',
            },
            {
                'AttributeName': 'SongTitle',
                'KeyType': 'RANGE',
            },
        ],
        ProvisionedThroughput={
            'ReadCapacityUnits': 5,
            'WriteCapacityUnits': 5,
        },
        TableName='test',
    )
except dynamodb_client.exceptions.ResourceInUseException:
    # do something here as you require
    pass
```

**Example 2**

```
import boto3

dynamodb_client = boto3.client('dynamodb')


table_name = 'test'
existing_tables = dynamodb_client.list_tables()['TableNames']

if table_name not in existing_tables:
    response = dynamodb_client.create_table(
        AttributeDefinitions=[
            {
                'AttributeName': 'Artist',
                'AttributeType': 'S',
            },
            {
                'AttributeName': 'SongTitle',
                'AttributeType': 'S',
            },
        ],
        KeySchema=[
            {
                'AttributeName': 'Artist',
                'KeyType': 'HASH',
            },
            {
                'AttributeName': 'SongTitle',
                'KeyType': 'RANGE',
            },
        ],
        ProvisionedThroughput={
            'ReadCapacityUnits': 5,
            'WriteCapacityUnits': 5,
        },
        TableName=table_name,
    )
```

**Example 3**

```
import boto3

dynamodb_client = boto3.client('dynamodb')

try:
    response = dynamodb_client.describe_table(TableName='test')
except dynamodb_client.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException:
    # do something here as you require
    pass
```

Comment: With `describe_table` I get `AttributeError: 'dynamodb.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'describe_table'`.

Comment: That is because you're using service resource instead of client. Check this line in your code: `dynamodb_client = boto3.client('dynamodb')`

Comment: Example 3 is great, but I was getting a ClientError thrown:
```
        dynamodb = boto3.resource(self._dynamodb_resource_name, region_name=self._region, endpoint_url=self._endpoint_url)
        # Try removing the table and ignore if it does not exist
        table = dynamodb.Table(self._tableName)
        try:
            table.delete()
        except ClientError as e:
            if e.response['Error']['Code'] != 'ResourceNotFoundException':
                raise e
```

Comment: The code doesn't look like what I had posted above. Where did you get the code from? Is it working for you and where is `ClientError` imported from?

Comment: So these exceptions only work with boto.client and not resource it seems.
So I'd imagine it's better just to use boto.client as opposed to boto3.resource?

Comment: The exception handling described will work with the client API, but is there anyway to capture exceptions from the resource API? For example `boto3.resource("dynamodb").Table("table_that_doesnt_exist")` will raise `ResourceNotFoundException` but I can't capture with this use case.

Answer (score 18):

```
import boto3

from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

TABLE_NAME = "myTableName"
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', endpoint_url="https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")

table = dynamodb.Table(TABLE_NAME)

try:
    response = client.describe_table(TableName=TABLE_NAME)

except ClientError as ce:
if ce.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ResourceNotFoundException':
    print "Table " + TABLE_NAME + " does not exist. Create the table first and try again."
else:
    print "Unknown exception occurred while querying for the " + TABLE_NAME + " table. Printing full error:"
    pprint.pprint(ce.response)
```

Comment: Thank you for this!  I was losing what was left of my hair.

Comment: I wrote this 3 years ago. Try getting a `client` object from the `dynamodb` object. That's my best guess right now.

Answer (score 12):

Alternate approach if you do not want to use [`boto3.client`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#client) but only [`boto3.resource`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#service-resource):

```
import boto3

database = boto3.resource('dynamodb', endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000")    

table_name  = 'MyTable'
table_names = [table.name for table in database.tables.all()]

if table_name in table_names:
    print('table', table_name, 'exists')
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use **describe table** API to determine whether the table exists.

**Sample code:**

```
from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility
import os
os.environ["TZ"] = "UTC"
import boto3

client = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2', endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000")



response = client.describe_table(
    TableName='Movies'
)    

print(response)
```

**If table exists:-**

- You will get the response

**If table doesn't exists:-**

- You will get `ResourceNotFoundException`

  botocore.errorfactory.ResourceNotFoundException: An error occurred (ResourceNotF
  oundException) when calling the DescribeTable operation: Cannot do operations on
  a non-existent table

**Another way:-**

Alternatively, you could use [`table.wait_until_exists()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.25.1/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.wait_until_exists). from the docs:

> Waits until this Table is exists. This method calls
> DynamoDB.Waiter.table_exists.wait() which polls.
> DynamoDB.Client.describe_table() every 20 seconds until a successful
> state is reached. An error is returned after 25 failed checks.
>
> See also: [AWS API Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/goto/WebAPI/dynamodb-2012-08-10/DescribeTable)
>
> **Request Syntax**
>
> ```
> table.wait_until_exists()
> ```
>
> **Returns**
>
> `None`

Comment: I like your code but can't figure out how to import the `botocore.errorfactory.ResourceNotFoundException`. I keep getting `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ResourceNotFoundException'`. I'm imported `boto3` and `botocore`.

Comment: @anon58192932 did you figure out how to import that exception? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @Phito sorry for the delay I just got back into work. Please see my answer that I'll be posting on how to check for the exception. It can't be imported directly as far as I understand.

Comment: @Phito: I have edited my answer to include example codes on how to catch exceptions in boto3.

Comment: @anupsabraham I didn't find the exact syntax to catch the exception so posting an example here
`_cwevents_client: BaseClient = _master_session.client('events', region_name=aws_region)
            try:
                _cwevents_client.describe_rule(Name=ruleName)
                logger.info("Determined that guarddutyAlert rule already exists")
            except _cwevents_client.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException:
                logger.info("Creating the guarddutyAlert CloudWatch rule")`

Comment: @Gautam The question is specific to `dynamodb`. Read my accepted answer above. I'm sure you can find similar exceptions in case of `cloudwatch events` too.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [.table_status](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.table_status) attr of any boto3 Table instance object. It returns it's status if exists (CREATING, UPDATING, DELETING, ACTIVE) or throws exception `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: Requested resource not found: Table: <YOUR_TABLE_NAME> not found`. You can wrap those conditions into try / except to have full info on the current table state.

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2')
table = dynamodb.Table('your_table_name_str')

try:
  is_table_existing = table.table_status in ("CREATING", "UPDATING",
                                             "DELETING", "ACTIVE")
except ClientError:
  is_table_existing = False
  print "Table %s doesn't exist." % table.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that it kind of depends on if you are using client or resource. If you use `boto3.client()`, you can use the 3 methods the accepted answer suggested. If you are using `boto3.resource()`, you can only use `dynamodb_resource.create_table()` and check exceptions.

```py
try:
    table = dynamodb_resource.create_table(
        ...
    )
    table.meta.client.get_waiter('table_exists').wait(TableName=your_table_name)
except ResourceInUseException:
    # do sth here
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this will have a slight risk if there are more than 10 tables between table.split(0, -1) and table. However, it does save throwing exceptions and the like.
Alas the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ListTables.html (examples) imply the the first table in the returned list will be the search item, it is not the case..

class Dynamo {

```
private m_db!: DynamoDB;

private async ensure_table(name: string) {
    const search = await this.db().listTables({
        ExclusiveStartTableName: name.slice(0, -1),
        Limit: 10 });
    const exists = search.TableNames?.includes(name);
    exists || await this.create_table(name);
}

private async create_table(name: string) {
   // create the table here 
}

 
private db(): DynamoDB { 
    return this.m_db || (this.m_db = this.create_db()); 
}


private create_db = (): DynamoDB => { 
    return new DynamoDB({apiVersion: "2012-08-10"}); }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the convenient resource API while still handling and catching the exceptions from the client API level, because you can access the client from the resource! This makes the method of checking if table exists the most elegant I have found:

```
resource = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='eu-north-1')

def table_exists(table_name: str) -> bool:
    try:
        resource.Table(table_name).table_status
    except resource.meta.client.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException:
        return False
    return True

print(table_exists('dummy_table'))
```